# Can't write an SMS for some of my contacts

Tags: contacts, sms, lg-optimus-one

I'm using an LGP500 Android Phone (Android 2.2). In the default SMS application, when I select a discussion, I see the previous SMS (both sent and received), and there's a text area at the bottom of the screen to write a new message.

For most of my contacts, this behavior is working correctly, but for a few of them (which I use quite often), the text area is not shown. Those contact have a mobile phone number, and I can send SMS using the long way (create a new sms, search the contact ...).

Does anybody have an idea of the cause or the solution ?

**Edit** I tried a few things to fix this : clearing the data, deleting any previous sms history, changing the phone number from the local (06xxxxxxxx) to international (+336xxxxxxxx) format (french phone numbers), changing the mobile phone number as default phone for the contact, in vain.

Comment: Is their number formatted differently from your other contacts?

Comment: Does the problem exist if you use a SMS app replacement such as Handcent?

Comment: Nope... Some contacts use the classic french format (06########), some others use the international format (+336########). I already tried to switch the number format, but in any case some contacts have the text area, others don't.

Comment: It's working correctly with Handcent, but I want to use the default SMS app if possible.

Comment: @XGouchet: Really?  You prefer the default SMS over Handcent?  You're the first person I know that's said that.  Everyone I know that's tried Handcent loves it.

Comment: @MBraedley Well i just need a simple SMS with no fancy features, so yeah I really prefer the default SMS app.

Comment: Is there anything different about these contacts? Stored on the SIM, perhaps? Or their phone number is not marked as "Mobile"?

Comment: @Al Everett nope, nothing different, the phone number is marked as mobile, and all my contacts are saved on my Google account.

Comment: I have related issue so would be interested to see answers: sometimes I am able to write the text of the SMS _reply_ but when I hit send it gives me "_Invalid number_" error. If I save it to Drafts and then try to send it from there, it works... Not the same problem but may be similar in a way of fixing. Let's hope for good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem i face with few contacts on my P500 too! Try merging contacts with their FB account or twitter account or just create a Buffer account and join them. It works after that. Not a great solution but been working that way now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is happening but you may be able to fix it by clearing the data from your messaging app.  From the home screen you go to `settings >  Applications > Manage Applications` then choose the Messaging app (or whatever your sms app is called).  If the option to clear the cache is there try that first but most likely you'll have to choose to "Clear Data".  I believe this will delete all the messages you have saved so keep this in mind.

Comment: This is not working, in fact event after clearing data, I still see my messages. I guess they are stored in another application or service but I don't know which one.

Comment: How about deleting and re-adding the contact?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with this has been with non-mobile type numbers. If you happen to have multiple numbers for a contact, and for some reason it happens to select the `Home` or `Work` number rather than the `Mobile`, it will disallow you to send text messages to these numbers. Have you checked to make sure the number you're sending it to is classified as mobile?

Comment: Yyes the phone number I send to is classified as mobile (I also made it the default number for thosr contacts).

Answer (score 0):

It may because the Messaging app "Only Mobile Numbers" setting enabled, try to disable it.
On Messaging App:

```
Menu > Settings > Extra Settings > Only Mobile Numbers
```

Comment: I do not have this extra settings in the sms app settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you are using the stock messaging app of android 2.2? (maybe you could be using a modified version by your manufacturer which may be buggy). Anyways try the following (which is for froyo's default messaging app)

- Go to Text Message Settings > "Manage SIM card messages" (check if any messages are there and try to move it back from it).
- Go to your conversation, Long press the "menu options" softkey on your android to get the keyboards and start typing to see if the field pops back.

Comment: I don't know if the manufacturer changed something but it looks a lot like the stock app. I tried what you suggested, there was no sms ln the sim card at all, and a long press on the menu button does not make pop up the soft keyboard on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some contact information got corrupted.  Try re-syncing the contacts on the phone.

`Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> All`, scroll down to "Contacts" app and tap on it, select "Clear data".  Do the same for the "Contacts Storage" app.  This should clear all contacts data.  Now go to `Menu -> Settings -> Accounts & sync`, go into every account you have and toggle the "Sync Contacts" option off and back on.  This should force an immediate re-sync.